# How can you obtain the group_by value for use in passing to a function?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use dplyr to apply a function to a data frame that is grouped using the group_by function. I am applying a function to each row of the grouped data using do(). I would like to obtain the value of the group_by variable so that I might use it in a function call.

So, effectively, I have-

```
tmp <-
  my_data %>%
  group_by(my_grouping_variable) %>%
  do(my_function_call(data.frame(x = .$X, y = .$Y),
                      GROUP_BY_VARIABLE)
```

I'm sure that I could call unique and get it...

```
do(my_function_call(data.frame(x = .$X, y = .$Y),
                    unique(.$my_grouping_variable))
```

But, it seems clunky and would inefficiently call unique for every grouping value.

Is there a way to get the value of the group_by variable in dplyr?

I'm going to prematurely say sorry if this is a crazy easy thing to answer. I promise that I've exhaustively searched for an answer.

Comment: More efficient than `unique` (though just as clunky) would be `first(.$my_grouping_variable)`. I'd encourage you to think about general cases - you seem to be assuming that there is only one grouping variable, but of course you could have a tibble grouped by multiple columns of varying classes. Presumably if there were a `this_group()` function it would need to return a named list or single row data frame with each grouping variable and its current value.

Answer (score 2):

First, if necessary, check if it's a grouped data frame: `inherits(data, "grouped_df")`.

If you want the subsets of data frames, you could nest the groups:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest()
```

Usually, you won't nest within the pipe-chain, but check in your function:

```
your_function(.x) <- function(x) {
  if(inherits(x, "grouped_df")) x <- nest(x)
}
```

Your function should then iterate over the list-column `data` with all grouped subsets. If you use a function within mutate, e.g.

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(abc = your_function_call(.x))
```

then note that your function directly receives the values for each group, passed as class `structure`. It's a bit difficult to explain, just try it out and debug `your_function_call` step by step...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groups()`, however a SE version of this does not exist so I'm unsure of its use in programming.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, mpg)

groups(df)

[[1]]
cyl

[[2]]
mpg
```

Comment: I think you can index groups(df)[[i]]

Comment: There is `group_indicies()` if you want the index.